# Select Column by comparing with another table column

Tags: mysql

i have two tables containers , sell

containers

```
--------------------------------------
| cont_id | cont_no | cont_condition |
--------------------------------------
|    1    |   A50   |  blaaablabla   |
|    2    |   A51   |  blaaablabla   |
|    3    |   J82   |  blaaablabla   |
|    4    |   S71   |  blaaablabla   |
--------------------------------------
```

sell

```
--------------------------------------
| sell_id | cont_no | cont_condition |
--------------------------------------
|    1    |   A50   |  blaaablabla   |
|    2    |   A51   |  blaaablabla   |
--------------------------------------
```

now i want select cont_no from containers table which are not in sell table (A50 AND A51 SOLD filter them and have to show rest of containers )

eg : expecting output like this

containers

```
--------------------------------------
| cont_id | cont_no | cont_condition |
--------------------------------------
|    3    |   J82   |  blaaablabla   |
|    4    |   S71   |  blaaablabla   |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: SInce you did not try anything here is a hint `left join` and `is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Left Excluding JOIN** -  this query will return all of the records in the left table (`containers`) that do not match any records in the right table (`sell`).

```
select cont_id, cont_no, cont_conditio from containers
left join sell on containers.cont_no = sell.cont_no
where sell.cont_no is null
```

The great visual explanation for different types of JOINs is there: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN with second table key is null.

```
select  cont_id, cont_no, cont_conditio from containers left join sell on containers.cont_no = sell.cont_no where sell.cont_no is nul
```